# How to block ads on TextNow using Google Chrome Incognito with both AdBlock AND AdBlock Plus extentions?

Tags: browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

Using Windows 7 Home Premium 32-Bit on Google Chrome Incognito with both of the extensions AdBlock and AdBlock Plus, I want to block as many ads as possible on every website or page that I visit.

Currently,when I open my TextNow account, it just endlessly loads the page so the account is useless,but when I disable AdBlock and allow TextNow in AdBlock Plus all it does is constantly load the ads and while it loads I can do nothing until it stops.

Before adding the AdBlock and AdBlock Plus while having TextNow open, I'd not see ANY ads on TextNow and now I do since I must disable and allow these extensions as applicable yet the page/website just loads and loads and loads even when I click to stop the loading.
Prior to both extensions I didn't see any ads and it was working fine without endless loading or losing any of the functions.

I've tried everything that I can think of to do and nothing I do works or even partially works. There's very little I know about computers, but I'm learning as time goes by both experience and reading stories from others.

Please try and help me out with step-by-step answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just allow them to run on incognito mode:

1. Go to your *Extensions* settings.
2. Check the *Allow in incognito mode* checkbox.

I also recommend you that you leave *only one* ad-blocker and import the blocking lists to the other, they may well be interfering with each other. You can also disable the *Allow some non-intrusive ads* option to block even more ads on adblock plus (I think adblock has that option too):

1. Click the ABP button.
2. Click the *Settings* option.
3. Disable such option